# A closed expression involving Hermite polynomials

Tags: special-functions, polynomials

I stumbled upon the following integral:

$$\int e^{-\left(\frac{\gamma}{2} + ip \right)^2} H_n \left( q-\frac{\gamma}{2} \right) H_n \left( q+\frac{\gamma}{2} \right) \, d\gamma \, ,$$

and I really need a closed form of it. I'm pretty sure it exists, and probably in terms of $\Gamma$ functions, since

$$ \int e^\frac{-\gamma^2}{2} H_n(\gamma) d\gamma = 4^n \sqrt{2} \,\Gamma \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) \, .$$

The problem is that *Mathematica* can't compute this in closed form, although it can do it term by term and hint that a closed expression probably exists:

```
Table[Integrate[
 HermiteH[i, q + 1/2 \[Gamma]] HermiteH[i, 
   q - 1/2 \[Gamma]] Exp[-(\[Gamma]/2 + I p)^2], {\[Gamma], -Infinity,
   Infinity}],{i,0,2}]
```

gives

$$\left\{2 \sqrt{\pi },4 \sqrt{\pi } \left(2 p^2+2 q^2-1\right),16 \sqrt{\pi } \left(2 \left(p^4+2 p^2 \left(q^2-1\right)+q^4\right)-4
   q^2+1\right)\right\} \, .$$

Can someone give me a tip?

Comment: Use a generating function for Hermit polynomials $\exp(2xt-t^2)=\sum_n H_n(x) t^n/n!$

Comment: How would that help, since I don't have a summation?

Comment: But you know how to extract each term using series.

Comment: My suggestion is not to use Mathematica, but to consult a table of integrals like Abramowitz and Stegun.

Comment: Can we make any assumptions about the parameters - Real, Integer, Positive...?

Comment: All parametres are real!

Comment: Is `i` (or `n` in your original integral) limited to integer values?

Comment: @mikado Yes. They're both positive integers. Abramowitz and Stegun have nothing on Hermite polynomials that are functions of different arguments. I was thinking about using the contour representation of Hermite polynomials and integrating inside, but it didn't get me far, although that might lead to a solution. I can update that if it helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an integral I happen to have worked with before. The answer is a Laguerre polynomial, as can be verified like this for the first three indices as in the question:

```
ll = 
  2 Table[LaguerreL[i, 2 (p^2 + q^2)] (-2)^i Sqrt[Pi] i!, {i, 0, 2}];

l1 = Table[
   Integrate[
    HermiteH[i, q + 1/2 γ] HermiteH[i, q - 1/2 γ] Exp[-(γ/2 + I p)^2], 
   {γ, -Infinity, Infinity}], {i, 0, 2}];

Simplify[ll/l1]

(* ==> {1, 1, 1} *)
```

Here, `ll` is my closed form, and `l1` is the list copied from the question. I verify that they give the same answers by forming the ratios.

The formula originally comes from Gradshtein and Ryzhik, equation 7.377, and I used it in my very first paper, [Conductance quantization and backscattering](http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/papers/) below equation (13) to expand a shifted harmonic oscillator function in terms of the unshifted one. That's why I remembered where to look this up...

Comment: I can't thank you enough. Indeed, I just remembered the seminal work by Groenewald, "On the principles of quantum mechanics", uses thais formula to calculate the Wigner function for a harmonic oscillator. Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

It is interesting to solve this integral without relying on *Gradshteyn and Ryzhik*. As I suggested in the comments, one can use the generating function approach. The solution consists of 7 steps. Human input is needed on step 5. All other steps are pretty much automatic.

1. Substitute  generating functions
   $\exp(2xt-t^2)=\sum_n\frac{1}{n!}H_n(x)t^n$ and integrate

   ```
   g[1] = Integrate[Exp[-(Y/2 + I p)^2] Exp[2(q-Y/2)t-t^2] Exp[2(q+Y/2)s-s^2], 
                  {Y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
   ```

   We have for `g[1]=`$2 \sqrt{\pi } e^{-2 i p (s-t)+2 q (s+t)-2 s t}=\sum_{mn}\frac{1}{m!n!}I_{m,n}(p,q)t^ms^n$, where we are interested in $I_{n,n}(p,q)$.
2. Next we need to extract from this generating function coefficients
   in front of $t^ns^n$, i.e., diagonal elements of the expansion. Let
   us introduce the substitution `{t -> x/y, s -> y}` and search for
   coefficients in front of $x^n y^0$.

   ```
   g[2] = g[1] /. {t -> x/y, s -> y};
   ```
3. It is the exponential function with the $2\sqrt\pi$ prefactor and
   power:

   ```
   pow = Cases[g[2], Exp[x_] -> x] // First;
   ```

   i.e., `g[2]=2 Sqrt[Pi] Exp[pow]`
4. We simplify the argument of the exponent little bit:

   ```
   g[3] = Collect[pow, {y, x}]
   ```

   $2(q+ip)\,x/y+2(q-ip)\,y -2 x$
5. Now, we can easily extract the coefficient in front of $y^0$ in the
   series expansion of `g[2]` (this is the only nontrivial step in this
   derivation). For the summation, we rely on the amazing capabilities
   of Mathematica:

   ```
   g[4] = 2 Sqrt[Pi] E^(-2 x) Sum[1/(2 n)! Binomial[2n,n] (2 I p + 2 q)^n x^n 
           (-2 I p + 2 q)^n,{n, 0, Infinity}]
   (*2 E^(-2 x) Sqrt[Pi] Hypergeometric0F1[1, 4 (p^2 + q^2) x]*)
   ```
6. At this point we have the generating function, i.e., $2\sqrt{\pi} e^{-2x}{\,}_0F_1\left[;1,(p^2 + q^2) x\right]=\sum_n \frac{1}{(n!)^2}I_{n,n}x^n$. Finally, we extract
   corresponding series coefficients.

   ```
   g[5] = (n!)^2 SeriesCoefficient[g[4], {x, 0, n}];
   ```
7. The solution in terms of the *generalized hypergeometric function*
   can be simplified as follows:

   ```
   FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[g[5]], Assumptions -> n >= 0 && n \[Element] Integers]
   ```

And we are done:

```
g[6]=(-1)^n 2^(1 + n) n! Sqrt[Pi] LaguerreL[n, 2 (p^2 + q^2)]
```

Comment: Actually you're still using Gradshteyn & Ryzhik because the generating function from which you start is equation GR 8.957...

Comment: @Jens GR is such a comprehensive book that I am not surprised that the generating function of Hermite polynomials can be found there. I this case, I vaguely remembered that the function has an exponential form which is useful here. To be sure I just check it on wiki. But thank you to putting a reference to this equation in GR, this makes the answer more complete.